# Angular not counting objects in array

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to count an array and put the result in my view. Keep getting zero, whatever I try.

View:

```
{{custTotal}}
```

Ctrl:

```
  $scope.customers = []; //loaded from a factory

  function getTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    total = $scope.customers.length;  
    $scope.custTotal = total;
  }

  function init(){
    $scope.customers = customersFactory.getCustomers();
    getTotal();
  }

  init();
```

Tried watching the $scope, did not help:

```
$scope.$watch('customers', function() {
    $scope.ordersTotal = $scope.customers.length;
  });
```

Other information loads fine. No clue!

**Update**:

Still no lead on the solution. The object loads fine. $scope works. I am using Firebase for backend. If I change the getTotal() method to this:

```
  function getTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    total = $scope.customers; // Remove .length  
    $scope.custTotal = total;
  }
```

my {{custTotal}} will load this into the view:

```
 [{"city":"Rutten","id":1,"joined":"2011-05-02","name":"Tanner","orders":[{"id":2,"product":"Left shoe","total":2.95}],"$id":"0","$priority":null},{"city":"San Francisco","id":2,"joined":"2011-12-12","name":"Joffrey","orders":[{"id":1,"product":"Right shoe","total":4.95},{"id":2,"product":"Left shoe","total":9.95}],"$id":"1","$priority":null}]
```

So it loads my object, but it **refuses to count its length**

Answer (score 0):

You should trigger `getTotal()` function after `getCustomer()` is done requesting the server.

You init should look something like this:

```
function init() {
  // Assuming your getCustomers function returns a promise.
  $scope.customers = customersFactory.getCustomers().
   then(function(){
      $scope.getTotal();
   });
}
```

Comment: This is not working as I am not returning a promise. My factory returns an object, which I use freely in my view, but for some reason I can't count items in the array.

Comment: But your `getCustomers()` would be making a server call right? If so then `getTotal()` should trigger after the request to server is complete.

Comment: well, maybe you are right, but this solution of yours is not working anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you skip the intermediate variable in just evaluate:

```
{{ customers.length }}
```

Comment: it works fine, however I need to get the method above working somehow for a deeper iteration later on.

Comment: Present more code. The behavior you described is strange and I cant see it happening based on the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a callback in the factory so that your result looks something like that:

```
  $scope.customers = []; //loaded from a factory
  $scope.custTotal = 0;

  function init(){
    customersFactory.getCustomers(
        function(resultArray){
            $scope.customers = resultArray.slice();
            $scope.custTotal = $scope.customers.length;
        }
    );
 }
 init()
```

and then you call the callback function within your factory within the callback of the server call you (probably?) make ... with this approach you are sure to wait until the data has actually been loaded.